# How to create random code with some fixed prefix in php?

Tags: php, random

how to generate a unique Code which will be a 8 Digit code code 1-2 Represent fixed (ZX), Code 3-8 are auto generation of Code. Ex: “ZX23456X”. ?

The format of the unique Code should be as follows:
1) one alphabet.
2) followed by 5 numeric values
3) followed by first two should be fixed "ZX"

Comment: Have you even attempted this? This is really quite trivial. Why not just `"ZX" . $randomNumber`?

Comment: how random should it be? if it should be seriously random i suggest you randomize it; verify if it was never earlier generated [database will come handy here] and save to the database. if you expect to see a lot of concurrency you should wrap it in transactions/locking or at least use process id as part of the number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$start = 'ZX';
$characters = array_merge(range('A','Z'), range('0','9'));
for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    $rand = mt_rand(0, count($characters)-1);
    $start .= $characters[$rand];
}
echo $start;
```

Answer (score 2):

What about [`UniqId()`](http://php.net/uniqid) ?

```
function UniqCode($prefix="ZX",$length=8)
{
   return substr(strtoupper(uniqid($prefix)), 0, $length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try use `<?php echo substr(uniqid('ZX'), 0, 8); ?>`, see https://www.php.net/uniqid

Answer (score 0):

try

```
echo "ZX".substr(md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 0, 8);
```